# How to assign all the component subscription into single variable like array and unsubscribe everything

Tags: angular, rxjs

Created the component with multiple subscription, also on ngOnDestroy doing the unsubscribe.

It's working as expected but created the multiple variable for each subscription, how can i do with single variable like pushing in to array or json?

tried below logic

```
this.sub[1] = this.crossCommunicate.toggleEdit.subscribe(
      (showedit: any) => {
         this.showedit = showedit;
      }
    );
```

Pushed all the subscribes by key value, if any key value missing or mismatched may error come.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    for(let i=1; i < this.sub.length ; i++){
      this.sub[i].unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Is the any better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TakeUntil:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class APPcomponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    }

ngOnInit() { 
    this.someService.SomeCall(parametesr)
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                some result
            },
            error => { },
            () => {
            });

    this.someService.SecondCall(parametesr)
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                some result
            },
            error => { },
            () => {
            });

}

someProcedure() {
this.someService.ThirdCall(parametesr)
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                some result
            },
            error => { },
            () => {
            });
}


ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    }
```

Comment: Error TS2339: Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type 'Subject<{}>'. while using the takeUntil for the subject.

toggleEdit is the subject in my application.

Comment: @Govinda raj Have you imported:` import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
                         import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';`

Comment: Yes ,imported the necessary stuffs.

Comment: @Govinda raj It is strange. I use this in all of my projects to unsubscribe. Can you paste that code where you get error? And which angular version you use?

Comment: @Govinda raj Try this one: `import { takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";` It depends on version of RXJS also how you will import it.

Comment: import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();

this.sub[2] = this.crossCommunicate.toggleEdit
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe(
      (showedit: any) => {
        console.log(60, showedit);
        this.showedit = showedit;
      }
    );

error TS2339: Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type 'Subject<{}>'
error TS2339: Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tried in both subject and observable.

Comment: @Govinda raj have that helped you? Is it working now?

Comment: @Govinda raj The problem is in this part of code: `this.sub[2] = this.crossCommunicate.toggleEdit .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe) .subscribe( (showedit: any) => { console.log(60, showedit); this.showedit = showedit; } );` It should be without `this.sub[2] = ` If you use `takeUntil` you don't need that. Write it like  `this.crossCommunicate.toggleEdit .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe) .subscribe( (showedit: any) => { console.log(60, showedit); this.showedit = showedit; } );`

Comment: However after removing assignment to the variable same issue,  I hope just assigning to variable

Comment: @Govinda raj what is your code behind `this.crossCommunicate.toggleEdit` what you do there?

Comment: Sharing the data between the components using the subject.

Comment: @Govinda raj Without knowing your code, I'cant help you that much, but please reade the text from this [link](http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/) that may help you to find solution for your problem with unsubcribing. There you will find several methods and among them TakeUntil:

Comment: after importing takeUntill from import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil' working fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can create one `Subscription` object and add everything into it using its `add` method.

```
this.subscriptions = new Subscription();

const sub1 = this.whatever$.subscribe(...);
const sub2 = this.foobar$.subscribe(...);

this.subscriptions
  .add(sub1)
  .add(sub2);
```

And then unsubscribe everything:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}
```

Maybe a also have a look at this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2769

Comment: Created the sub1 and sub2 variables, is it possible to use any method instead of creating the variables?

Comment: Well you could use `this.subscriptions.add(this.whatever$.subscribe(...))` but that's hard to read I think.